# A custom route to an entity form will not pass the entity

Tags: forms, routes

I want a custom route to the normal user form. So, I've added an entry to the routing file that directs my custom route to the canonical form of the `User` entities:

```
my_profile_form:
  path: '/user/{user}/my-profile-form'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\user\ProfileForm'
    _title: 'My profile form'
  requirements:
    _role: 'administrator'
```

When I try to open `/user/1/my-profile-form` with my browser, I see the following error message:

> Error: Call to a member function getEntityTypeId() on null in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityForm->getBaseFormId() (line 106 of ...web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityForm.php)

It seems that with my custom route the form does not know who the user is.

**What magic must happen to inform the form about the user?**

Comment: Have you tried adding `type: entity:my_entity_type` as mentioned [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameters-in-routes/parameter-upcasting-in-routes#s-special-case-entity-parameters)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `_entity_access`

```
my_profile_form:
....
  requirements:
    _role: 'administrator',
    _entity_access: user.update
   user: \d+
```

See [EntityAccessCheck](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityAccessCheck.php/function/EntityAccessCheck%3A%3Aaccess/8.2.x)

Answer (score 1):

Custom access check is written to check whether the logged in user is same as of user id passed in the parameter

```
my_module.user.profile:
  path: '/user/{user}/profil'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'user.profil'
    _title: 'Profil'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'user.update'
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\my_module\Access\MyModuleUserAccess::editProfil'
    user: \d+
  options:
    _admin_route: FALSE
```

Comment: Hallo, @sudesh-solaskar! Thank you for your answer! The argument `_entity_form` is the the solution. Entity forms need this argument in the route definition, instead of `_form`. We can confirm this when setting a breakpoint here: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/86fd930b676b3a9713d1a2299b70797c957c4565/core/modules/user/src/Entity/UserRouteProvider.php#L49 . Maybe, you could clarify your answer.